# Having an issue with processing post request in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Having an issue with processing post request in node.js and it is showing the error: Cannot POST /index.html
Since body-parser is deprecated, I am stuck with this error

```js
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
  var num1 = Number(req.body.num1);
  var num2 = Number(req.body.num2);
  var result = num1+num2;
  res.send(String(result));
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Calculator</h1>
  <form action="index.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="First Number">
    <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Second Number">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Calculate</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get it. What is your requirement with these code snippets?

> Since body-parser is deprecated, I am stuck with this error

`body-parser` is now part of Express and you can just get it by writing,

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

> error: Cannot POST /index.html

The reason Express throw this error is because, you don't have matching POST route. Instead you have POST `/` route. I would suggest you to update the `<form>`'s action to `/` instead of `index.html`.

```html
<form action="/" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="First Number" />
  <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Second Number" />
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Sir ! This works just fine now.